# Unable to load Bootstrap into Angular CLI project

Tags: node.js, angular, sass, angular-cli, bootstrap-4

I've got a problem adding Bootstrap 4 RC6 to my Angular CLI project and I'm not sure what's going on - or how to describe it. My steps to create the project were as follows:

I've created a new project using Angular CLI with styles set to SASS using `ng new My_New_Project --style=sass.`

I've install node-sass using `npm install node-sass --save-dev.`

I've installed bootstrap 4 RC6 using `npm install bootstrap@4.0.0-alpha.6.`

At this point I added `@import '~bootstrap'` to my existing styles.scss and I'm getting a weird error as follows:

```
ERROR in ./~/css-loader?{"sourceMap":false,"importLoaders":1}!./~/postcss-loader?{"ident":"postcss"}!./~/sass-loader/lib/loader.js?{"sourceMap":false,"precision":8,"includePaths":[]}!./src/styles.scss
Module build failed:
undefined
  ^
      Invalid CSS after "if": expected "{", was "(typeof jQuery === "
      in C:\<path>\node_modules\bootstrap\dist\js\bootstrap.js (line 7, column 4)
 @ ./src/styles.scss 4:14-189
 @ multi ./src/styles.scss
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try import bootstrap like this

```
@import '~bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css';
```

also check the file structure

Answer (score 0):

First, you need to install bootstrap to your project. You can use the following command:
**`npm install bootstrap@latest --save`**
If you've already done installing the bootstrap, then use the following command to import it:
**`@import '~bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css';`**